# Create Shipment By Order Increment Id

Tags: magento2.4, rest-api, shipment

To create shipment by Rest API, I am using it and it is working fine.

**{base_url}/rest/V1/order/15/ship**

Parameter **15** is **order_id**.

I want to create shipment by **order increment id**.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally Magento2 directly not allowed to use those parameter, but you can use following steps.

1. Get the `order_id` from the `Order Increment Id`.
2. Now Call the API with the `order_id` parameter as above.

Comment: Can it possible in single API call?